# how to chose between two tasks in ansible using tags

Tags: ansible, yaml, gitlab-ci

I'd like to use tags to select specific set of tasks in the case of an installation or another in the an upgrade:
so the scenario let's say: I have a task A and a task B I'd like to use tags to select either A or B
here is what I have so far : a role where in my task/main.yml :

```
- name: "Configuration"
  include: 03-configuration.yml
  when: upgrade
  tags:
    - configuration
```

so I launch my playbook like this which leads me to go to the file 03-configuration.yml and plays everything in this file

```
ansible-playbook -v ThePlayBook.yml --tags "configuration"
```

the 03-configuration.yml file:

```
- name: "A"

- name: "B"
```

but as you can see in this file 03-configuration.yml I have the two task I'm talking about A and B so at this moment it will try to execute both of them, whereas I want to make use of a tag like  "installation" or "upgrade" to launch either one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, given the file

```yaml
shell> cat configuration.yml 
- debug:
    msg: installation
  tags: installation
- debug:
    msg: upgrade
  tags: upgrade
```

Include it in a playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: configuration.yml
      when: upgrade|default(false)|bool
      tags: configuration
```

When you run this playbook without any tag

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e upgrade=true
```

all tasks are executed

```yaml
TASK [debug] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: installation

TASK [debug] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: upgrade
```

When you run it with the *configuration* tag only

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e upgrade=true -t configuration
```

the file is included but no task is executed

```yaml
TASK [include_tasks] ********************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp8/configuration.yml for localhost
```

The `tags: configuration` is not inherited by the tasks in the included file. See [Tag inheritance for includes ...](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tag-inheritance-for-includes-blocks-and-the-apply-keyword). If you want to execute such a task both tags are needed if tags are specified on the command line. For example

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e upgrade=true -t configuration,installation
```

gives abridged

```yaml
TASK [debug] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: installation
```

See more details in [Tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tags).

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible for you to use an approach like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: "Config"
    include_tasks: install_update.yml
    tags:
      - config
```

```yaml
- name: "A"
  debug:
  tags: install

- name: "B"
  debug:
  tags: update
```

call it via

```
ansible-playbook ThePlayBook.yml --tags="config"
ansible-playbook ThePlayBook.yml --tags="config,install"
ansible-playbook ThePlayBook.yml --tags="config,update"
```

resulting into an output of

```
PLAY RECAP **********************
localhost                  : ok=1

...

TASK [A] ************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Hello world!

PLAY RECAP **********************
localhost                  : ok=2

...

TASK [B] ************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Hello world!

PLAY RECAP **********************
localhost                  : ok=2
```

**Further Readings**

- [What's the difference between `include_tasks` and `import_tasks`?](https://serverfault.com/a/875292/448950)